# IBM watson| remember the last entity/ intent

Tags: websphere, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Imagine I am working on a chatbot that helps to answer queries about loyalty program.

Set up:
Intent:
#requirement_of_membership, #award_of_membership

Entity:
@gold, @silver, @bronze

After user asks a question of "what is the requirement of gold membership" and receives answer from chatbot. Then, the user asks "what is its award". what should be configured in IBM watson to allow chatbot to remember the last entity value is @gold?

Similarly, After user asks a question of "what is the requirement of gold membership" and receives answer from chatbot. Then, the user asks "how about silver". what should be configured in IBM watson to allow chatbot to show user the answer of #requirement_of_membership + @silver?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for IBM Watson Assistant has a section dedicated to the topic of [retaining information across multiple dialog turns](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-runtime-context). You can use so-called context variables to store information (context) and access it later on. It is possible to update and delete those context variables when not used anymore.

Context variables can also be specified in slots and used with webhook results.